# How do I create an object list inside an object in perl?

Tags: list, perl, class, object, module

I'm newer in Perl, sorry for my dumb question.

I searched but I didn't found a way to do this.

I created a class that one attribute need to be a list of objects and I need to call this list later.

I tried to push the objects in a list I receive the message:

Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at...

My package

```
package Squid;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new
{
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {@_ };

  print "Creating new $class\n";

  $self->{'filas'} = [];

  bless ($self, $class);

  return $self;
}

1;
```

And this is the script:

```
use Squid;
use warnings;
use strict;


my $fila = FilaSquid->new("nome" => 'Fila 1', "profundidade" => 45);
my $fila2 = FilaSquid->new("nome" => 'Fila 2', "profundidade" => 7);

my $squid = Squid->new("versao" => '1.0', "origem" => 'C:\temp', "filas" => @filas);

print "\nA versao da fila eh ".$squid->{versao};
print "\nA origem da fila eh ".$squid->{origem}."\n";

foreach my $line ($squid->{filas}) {
    print $line->{nome}."\n";
}
```

Comment: The code you ran is not the code you show. `Global symbol "@filas" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @filas"?) at script.pl line 9.
script.pl had compilation errors.`. Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: There are several problems there: (1) `@filas` is not declared. Did you forgot to declare it and insert into it `$fila` and `$fila2`? (2) There isn't a module declaration for `FilaSquid`. (3) In your constructor, you're overwritting `$self->{'filas'}` even though you're also passing it as an argument. (4) You probably wan't to pass `@filas` as an `ARRAYREF`.

Answer (score 6):

First problem is this in `new`.

```
$self->{'filas'} = [];
```

You're initializing `$self->{'filas'}` to an empty array reference. That will blow away anything passed in via `new`.  What you probably want instead is:

```
$self->{filas} //= [];
```

Which is the same as:

```
$self->{filas} = $self->{filas} // [];
```

[`//` is the "defined-or" operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or). That says to only initialize `$self->{filas}` if it's undefined. It's a bit safer than using `||=` because there are some valid things which are false.

---

Second problem is how you're passing `filas` to `new`. That you're initializing `$self->{filas}` with an array *reference* is your clue.

```
my @filas = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

my $squid = Squid->new(
    "versao" => '1.0',
    "origem" => 'C:\temp',
    "filas" => @filas
);
```

This is like saying:

```
my $squid = Squid->new(
    "versao" => '1.0',
    "origem" => 'C:\temp',
    "filas" => 1,
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6
);
```

You've just stuck an extra bunch of stuff on the end of what's supposed to be an even-sized list to be used as a hash.

The `=>` operator is basically the same as a comma. It doesn't create pairs, it just allows you to leave out quotes around strings on its left hand side. `key => @values` isn't one pair, it's `key => $values[0], $values[1], $values[2], ...`. `new` tries to treat that list as a hash, and so long as there's an even number of elements it will "work".

Instead, you need to pass in an array *reference*. `key => \@values`.

```
my $squid = Squid->new(
    "versao" => '1.0',
    "origem" => 'C:\temp',
    "filas" => \@filas
);
```

Comment: Might want `[@filas]` there, not `\@filas`

Comment: @ysth Could be, if they want a copy. Since we don't know what it's going to be used for... \*shrug\*.

Comment: What ysth is getting at is that `\@filas` will cause changes to the array passed to the constructor and changes to the object to affect each other, which is unlikely to the be desired. `[ @filas ]` creates a new array that's a copy of the one passed as an argument, breaking that unfortunate linking. (I know you know this, Schwern. This is for the other readers.)

Comment: @ikegami I agree, but I flip it the other way around. Instead of making the caller decide what the object is going to do with the reference, I let the object decide and copy it if it needs to. Maybe it's not going to change it so the copy is a waste of memory? Maybe it wants to manipulate the caller's data? Dunno what it's doing with `@filas` so... \*shrug\*. Anyhow, that's all outside the scope of the question. They'll get there soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that you can insert numerous objects into another object without breaking encapsulation. It does not focus on any issues in your existing code, it just answers the question. In this example, `Two` holds numerous objects of class `One`. Each inner object has a name:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package One; {
    sub new {
        my ($class, %args) = @_;
        return bless {%args}, $class;
    }
    sub name {
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{name};
    }
}

package Two; {
    sub new {
        return bless {}, shift;
    }
    sub add {
        my ($self, %args) = @_;
        my $name = $args{name};
        $self->{objects}{$name} = One->new(name => $name);
    }
    sub get_names {
        my ($self) = @_;
        return keys %{ $self->{objects} };
    }
    sub inner_obj {
        my ($self, $name) = @_;
        return $self->{objects}{$name};
    }
}

package main;

my $two = Two->new;

$two->add(name => 'obj1');
$two->add(name => 'obj2');

# loop over each inner object by name

for my $name ('obj1', 'obj2'){
    print $two->inner_obj($name)->name . "\n";
}

# or let Two give you the list of names back, and iterate
# automatically

for ($two->get_names){
    print $two->inner_obj($_)->name . "\n";
}
```

Note that we're manually adding new objects in the main script. It is just as easy if you need to set up a list of objects within a module and not main... you'd just modify `Two::new()` to call its `add()` method internally.